# Is it possible to add a background to the entire height in pdf when it's converted with wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

Is it  possible to add a background color to the entire height in pdf when it's converted with wkhtmltopdf?

This css rule:

```
  html,body {
    height: 100%;
    backgorund-color: #ff0000;
  }
```

doesn't work :)

Converted html is automaticaly generated. It has from 1 to 3 pages.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me:

```
#test.html

<html>
<body style="background-color:#E6E6FA">
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And run command -

```
wkhtmltopdf --margin-bottom 0 --margin-top 0 test.html test1.pdf
```

For more wkhtmltopdf options check out this [manual](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html)